# How do you prove that vectors are linearly independent in $ \mathcal{C}[0,1]$?

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm presented with the question:

> Show that the given vectors are linearly independent in $\mathcal{C}[0,1]$:
>
> $x^{3/2}, x^{5/2}$

I'm having a terrible time understanding linearly algebra in general. I think my part of my problem with this question is understanding what the $\mathcal{C}[0,1]$ notation means. Beyond that, I'm still not exactly sure how to show this. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: @Tom Oldfield, how did you fix the exponents so that I don't make that mistake next time?

Comment: Hello, I edited your question to try and make it look I little nicer. I also changed the wording to make it clear that $x^{3/2}$ and $x^{5/2}$ were separate vectors, let me know if I changed anything I shouldn't have.

Comment: Also, for more info on how to include maths formatting, please see this post:
http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

(Essentially, put anything you want to format between two $ signs.)

Comment: Just out of curiosity, if I was given *f* (x), *g* (x), *and* *h* (x), would I just attempt to find values *a, b, c* such that *af+ bg + ch* = 0?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$C[0,1]$ usually denotes the collection of continuous functions $f: [0,1]\to \mathbb{R}$.  This is a vector space over $\mathbb{R}$, with multiplication defined pointwise: $(af)(x) = af(x)$.

What would it mean if two functions, $f,g\in C[0,1]$, were linearly *dependent*?  It would meant that there were two scalars, $a,b\in\mathbb{R}$, not both zero, such that $af + bg = 0$ as functions.  In other words, for all $x$, $af(x) + bg(x) = 0$.

To show that $f=x^{3/2}$ and $g=x^{5/2}$ are linearly independent, let's assume that such $a$ and $b$ exist, and try to show that they're both zero..  If such $a,b\in\mathbb{R}$ exist, then $ax^{3/2} + bx^{5/2} = 0$ for all $x$.  Let's try plugging in $x=1$—we get $a+b=0$.  Plugging in $x=1/4$, we get $a/8 + b/32=0$ (note: you could also plug in different values of $x$, but I chose these to keep the math as simple as possible).

Now, we can solve the two equations $a+b=0$ and $a/8+b/32=0$, to get $a=b=0$.  Ah, but this is exactly what we wanted to show: $x^{3/2}$ and $x^{5/2}$ cannot have a linear sum which equal zero unless it is the trivial sum, i.e. $0\cdot f + 0\cdot g = 0$.

Comment: You'd better pick 1 and 1/4, because 4 is not in the domain of $f$ and $g$. Doesn't really matter, of course, but it avoids having to point out that it really doesn't matter.

Comment: @Magdiragdag, is this because *C* [0,1]?

Comment: Thanks for all responses. This one was just the most inclusive.

Comment: @Magdiragdag: Fixed, thanks.

Answer (score 3):

$C[0,1]$ is the vector space of continuous functions from $[0,1]$ into $\mathbb{R}$. You can add functions, subtract them, there is a zero function, multiply by elements in $\mathbb{R}$, etc. Thus, it makes sense to ask about linearly independent elements of this vector space. Take the elements $x^{3/2}$ and $x^{5/2}$. We want to show that these are linearly independent, so that one is not the multiple of another by an element in $\mathbb{R}$. Can you show this?

Comment: Unfortunately, no... I'm not sure how to show that. I'm guessing it is what @Magdiragdag pointed out.

Comment: Hint: Suppose $x^{3/2} = cx^{5/2}$ for all $x\in [0,1]$. Divide both sides $x^{3/2}$ and see what you get.

Answer (score 3):

$\mathcal{C}[0,1]$ is the set of continuous functions from the interval $[0,1]$ to $\mathbb R$. So you're asked to show that the functions $f$ and $g$ on $[0,1]$ defined by $f(x) = x^{3/2}$ and $g(x) = x^{5/2}$ are linearly independent.

To show this, assume that $\lambda, \mu \in {\mathbb R}$ satisfy $\lambda f + \mu g = 0$, i.e., for all $x \in [0,1]$, $\lambda x^{3/2} + \mu x^{5/2} = 0$. Now plug in some values for $x$ and derive that $\lambda = \mu = 0$.

Answer (score 3):

$\alpha x^{3/2}+\beta x^{5/2} = 0$ $\Longrightarrow $
$$
x^{3/2}(\alpha + \beta x)=0
$$
$$
\beta x = -\alpha 
$$
or
$$
x^{3/2}=0
$$
Can you finish?

Answer (score 3):

Related problems: [(I)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/206823/show-that-yt-t-and-gt-t-lnt-are-linearly-independent), [(II)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/610409/are-functions-dependent).

**Hint:** You can use the [Wronskian](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wronskian).

> $$ W(f_1, \ldots, f_n) (x)= \begin{vmatrix} f_1(x) & f_2(x) & \cdots & f_n(x) \\ f_1'(x) & f_2'(x) & \cdots & f_n' (x)\\ \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\ f_1^{(n-1)}(x)& f_2^{(n-1)}(x) & \cdots & f_n^{(n-1)}(x) \end{vmatrix},\qquad x\in I. $$

In order for the functions to be linearly independent, then the Wronskian does not equal zero.

**Added:**

In your case, you want to prove

$$  W(x^{3/2}, x^{5/2}) (x)= \begin{vmatrix} x^{3/2} & x^{5/2}  \\ \frac{3}{2}x^{1/2} & \frac{5}{2}x^{3/2}  \end{vmatrix}$$

Now, you need to calculate the above determinant and prove it does not equal to zero.

Comment: I know the word but... no idea how to implement that solution. Perhaps an example?

Comment: @Amzoti: You are right. It just a typo. Thanks for the comment.

Comment: @rphello101 Since you seem so wide-eyed, I'll let you know that Mhenni is basically proposing fishing (and fishing practice, at that) with dynamite.  Effective perhaps, but dangerous without proper training, not so versatile out of its professional context, louder than the locals are likely to tolerate, and just plain unsportsmanlike.  In short, it works much better as a joke than as a practical solution.

Comment: @user33433: Check [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/206823/show-that-yt-t-and-gt-t-lnt-are-linearly-independent) answer and it will answer you.