# Linearly Independency of functions

Tags: linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations

Show if the functions are linearly independent

$x(t)=3$, $y(t)=3\sin^2t$, $z(t)= 4\cos^2t$

How can i show this?

Comment: Can you write out what you need to prove?

Comment: A [related problem](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/513882/how-do-you-prove-that-vectors-are-linearly-independent-in-mathcalc0-1).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you compute the Wronskian?

Comment: yes thanks!!!!!

Answer (score 3):

$x(t) - y(t) - \frac{3}{4} z(t) = 0$ for all $t$, so they are not linearly independent.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Knowing that $\sin^2t+\cos^2t=1$, it is obvious that $4y+3z=12$. Now multiply *x* with $-4$, and add it to the previous sum.